# date/numeric filter with jq

Tags: json, date, filter, jq

I have a json that looks like this (it's the result of simple jq filter):

```
[{
    "name": "Corrine",
    "firstname": "Odile",
    "uid": "PA2685",
    "roles": [{
            "role_name": "GQ",
            "start": "2012-06-20"
        },
        {
            "role_name": "HOUSE",
            "start": "2012-06-26"
        },
        {
            "role_name": "HOUSE",
            "start": "2017-06-28"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "name": "Blanche",
    "firstname": "Matthieu",
    "uid": "PA2685",
    "roles": [{
            "role_name": "SENATE",
            "start": "2014-06-20"
        },
        {
            "role_name": "SENATE",
            "start": "2012-06-26"
        },
        {
            "role_name": "SENATE",
            "start": "2012-06-28"
        }
    ]
}
]
```

I would like to filter in two ways:

- select only the first-level objects that have at least one `role_name` (inside the `roles` array) whose value is HOUSE;
- and from this group select only the ones that have at least one `start` whose date is in 2017 or after.

In the json above "Corrine Odile" would be the only one selected.

I tried some `with_entries(select(.value` expressions, but my I'm confused about how to deal with the dates as well as the "at least one" requirement.

Comment: Please follow the mcve guidelines https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. In particular, the sample input is not valid JSON, so it is not entirely clear what the “first-level objects” are.

Comment: Sorry the actual json is hundreds of lines long, so I used only the beginning and forgot to put the closing braces. It's fixed now @peak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Requirements of the form "at least one" can usually be satisfied efficiently using `any/2`, e.g.

```
any(.roles[]; .role_name == "HOUSE")
```

The check for the year can (apparently) be accomplished by:

```
.start | .[:4] | tonumber >= 2017
```

### Solution

To produce an array of objects satisfying the two conditions:

```
map(select(
  any(.roles[]; .role_name == "HOUSE") and
  any(.roles[]; .start[:4] | tonumber >= 2017) ))
```

`.start[:4]` is short for `.start|.[0:4]`

Comment: Thanks! That's perfect, I understand the syntax now. Only question is about the .[:4], what does it do?

Comment: It's an abbreviation for .[0:4]; see the Array/String Slice subsection of the online manual https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Basicfilters